# Unable to read excel files in Production environment but working in dev environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, spreadsheet

Using Spreadsheet GEM, I am able to read xls files in development environement.
As I move to production server, application is unable to read xls files.

Spreadsheet Gem is installed already. I am getting no error while uploading files. But the data in the xls files I am not able to read.

For. e.g my xls has 4 cols. A,B,C,D and data is present in 2 rows.

First Row has data : P1,P1,P3,P4
Second Row has data : Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4

In dev. env. I get the data as P1,P1,P3,P4 for first row and Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4 for second row.

But in prod. env. I get the no data. It gives blank for all columns.

Please help what can be the likely changes I am missing on to make it work in production environment too.

---

Spreadsheet Gem is installed already. I am getting no error while uploading files. But the data in the xls files I am not able to read.

For. e.g my xls has 4 cols. A,B,C,D and data is present in 2 rows.

First Row has data : P1,P1,P3,P4
Second Row has data : Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4

In dev. env. I get the data as P1,P1,P3,P4 for first row and Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4 for second row.

But in prod. env. I get the no data. It gives blank for all columns.

Comment: what error it gives you in production.log?

Answer (score 0):

HEY all, i have fix this problem , because i use deploy in nginx server ,nginx use X-Accel-Redirect for X-Sendfile as apache , must config this in production.rb

## For nginx:

config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect'

regards~!